# Xamarin forms media plugin crashes on iphone when using SQLiteNetExtensions

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

[Xamarin Forms Media Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) crashes on my iphone when using [SQLite-Net-Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions).

the line below hangs then crashes after retrieving an image, but works if i don't use the camera.

```
SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.ReadOperations.GetAllWithChildren<MyObject>(database, recursive: true);
```

below is the exception:

2018-03-26 16:21:37.303 (ProjectName).iOS[364:41332] Unable to get metadata: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: asset
  at Photos.PHImageManager.RequestImageData (Photos.PHAsset asset, Photos.PHImageRequestOptions options, Photos.PHImageDataHandler handler) [0x0008c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/Photos/PHImageManager.g.cs:170

at Plugin.Media.PhotoLibraryAccess.GetPhotoLibraryMetadata (Foundation.NSUrl url) [0x0004c] in :0

at Plugin.Media.MediaPickerDelegate+d__25.MoveNext () [0x00305] in :0

i would like to know why this is happening and possible way of resolving this issue?

Comment: I believe this was fixed already with a new beta of the media plugin for certain photos.

Comment: i just tried it a hour ago using version 3.1.3.222 ....i am still having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else having this problem, i manage to resolve it....the line that was actually cause this issue was not `SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.ReadOperations.GetAllWithChildren<MyObject>(database, recursive: true);`

but it was actually `SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(database, item);` ....that code was breaking because the foreign key relationship was incorrect....i am still not sure why that cause the camera to crash....but the issue is resolved now.